# How to use templates or dynamic content for php email sending

Tags: php, email, mailer

PHPMailer is a good option to send email, and mail() function too, but the thing is that generating dynamic content for the email body, and subject are not the best.

for example I've created a php file with the body templates or a class with the same, but are so difficult to maintain.

What do you recomend for organizing that code?

Is there a Way to create email templates? (like twig).
How do you organize folders and files?
Is there any doc recommendation for that?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's no different than what you're already doing in PHP to generate dynamic HTML. Except that instead of sending the generated HTML output via your web server to a client UA, you're sending it to an email UA via an MTA.

20 years ago someone thought to invent a good templating engine to generate dynamic content (it was called PHP). It turns out it's still incredibly useful today.

Let's say you have a template file that looks like this for your email.

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($row as $column) { ?>
        <td><?=$column?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Let's say have some templating system that renders these templates with perhaps something like this.

```
class Template {
    protected $templateFile = "";
    protected $templateVars = [];
    public function __construct($templateFile, Array $templateVars= []) {
        $this->templateVars = $templateVars;
        $this->templateFile = $templateFile;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        export($this->templateVars, EXTR_SKIP);
        ob_start();
        include $this->templateFile;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Now, you could expand upon this very simple abstraction of templating a bit further to include things like your email subject line, sender email address, etc...

```
class SendEmail {
    public function __construct($to, $subject, $template, Array $data) {
        $template = new Template($file, $data); // create the email template
        $this->emailBody = (string) $template; // generate the content
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }
    public function send() {
        // Send email using PHP mailer or whatever here
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this concept.. using a template class is a good Idea, but i mean how to template the HTML part?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Which part of that template wasn't HTML exactly?

Comment: How do you save your templates?  I mean, do you load it on a php variable?   Where was it before giving it to thd template class?

Answer (score -1):

```
$tempalteContent = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from newsletter_template where name like '%$template%'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($tempalteContent) > 0) {
    $validate = 0;
    $messageFinal = '';
    $message = '';
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tempalteContent);
    $template_id = $row['id'];
    $productInc = $row['productsInc'];
    $blogInc = $row['blogInc'];
    $templateMsg = htmlspecialchars_decode($row['description']);
    $divData = '';
    $blogData = '';
    if ($blogInc == 1 && $productInc == 1) {

        /*         * Product Query* */
        $productQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from newsletter_products where newsletter_tempalte_id = $template_id");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($productQuery) > 0) {

            $width = '';
            $website = "http://demo.com/";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($productQuery) > 2) {
                $width = '100%';
            } else if (mysqli_num_rows($productQuery) > 1) {
                $width = '100%';
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i <= mysqli_num_rows($productQuery); $i++) {
                $row[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($productQuery);
                $product_id[$i] = $row[$i]['product_id'];
                $productDetails[$i] = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from products where product_id = $product_id[$i]");
                if (mysqli_num_rows($productDetails[$i]) > 0) {
                    $rowproduct[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($productDetails[$i]);
                    $productName[$i] = $rowproduct[$i]['product_name'];
                    $productImg[$i] = $website . $rowproduct[$i]['product_img'];
                    $productDesp[$i] = htmlspecialchars_decode($rowproduct[$i]['product_desp']);
                    $divData .= "<div style='width:" . $width . ";float:left;padding:7px;text-align:justify'><span style='width:100%;padding-bottom:5px;float:left'><img src='" . $productImg[$i] . "' width='30%' height='30%' style='max-width:100px;max-height:100px'></span><b style='vertical-align:bottom'>" . $productName[$i] . "</b><span style='font-size:12px;'>" . $productDesp[$i] . "</span></div>";
                }
                $validate++;
            }
        }

        /*         * Blog Query* */

        $blogQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from newsletter_blogs where newsletter_template_id = $template_id");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($blogQuery) > 0) {

            $width = '';
            $website = "http://demo.com/";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($blogQuery) > 2) {
                $width = '100%';
            } else if (mysqli_num_rows($blogQuery) > 1) {
                $width = '100%';
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i <= mysqli_num_rows($blogQuery); $i++) {
                $row[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($blogQuery);
                $blog_id[$i] = $row[$i]['blog_id'];
                $blogDetails[$i] = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from blog where id = $blog_id[$i]");
                if (mysqli_num_rows($blogDetails[$i]) > 0) {
                    $rowblog[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($blogDetails[$i]);
                    $blogName[$i] = $rowblog[$i]['title'];
                    $blogImg[$i] = $website . $rowblog[$i]['img'];
                    $blogDesp[$i] = htmlspecialchars_decode($rowblog[$i]['desp']);
                    $blogData .= "<div style='width:100%;float:left;padding:7px;text-align:justify'><span style='width:100%;padding-bottom:5px;float:left'><img src='" . $blogImg[$i] . "' width='30%' height='30%' style='max-width:100px;max-height:100px'></span><b style='vertical-align:bottom'>" . $blogName[$i] . "</b><span style='font-size:12px;'>" . $blogDesp[$i] . "</span></div>";
                }
                $validate++;
            }
        }
        $message = $templateMsg . $divData . $blogData;
    } else if ($productInc == 1 && $blogInc == 0) {
        $productQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from newsletter_products where newsletter_tempalte_id = $template_id");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($productQuery) > 0) {

            $width = '';
            $website = "http://demo.com/";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($productQuery) > 2) {
                $width = '100%';
            } else if (mysqli_num_rows($productQuery) > 1) {
                $width = '100%';
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i <= mysqli_num_rows($productQuery); $i++) {
                $row[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($productQuery);
                $product_id[$i] = $row[$i]['product_id'];
                $productDetails[$i] = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from products where product_id = $product_id[$i]");
                if (mysqli_num_rows($productDetails[$i]) > 0) {
                    $rowproduct[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($productDetails[$i]);
                    $productName[$i] = $rowproduct[$i]['product_name'];
                    $productImg[$i] = $website . $rowproduct[$i]['product_img'];
                    $productDesp[$i] = htmlspecialchars_decode($rowproduct[$i]['product_desp']);
                    $divData .= "<div style='width:" . $width . ";float:left;padding:7px;text-align:justify'><span style='width:100%;padding-bottom:5px;float:left'><img src='" . $productImg[$i] . "' width='30%' height='30%' style='max-width:100px;max-height:100px'></span><b style='vertical-align:bottom'>" . $productName[$i] . "</b><span style='font-size:12px;'>" . $productDesp[$i] . "</span></div>";
                }
                $validate++;
            }
        }
        $message = $templateMsg . $divData;
    } else if ($blogInc == 1 && $productInc == 0) {
        $blogQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from newsletter_blogs where newsletter_tempalte_id = $template_id");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($blogQuery) > 0) {

            $width = '';
            $website = "http://demo.com/";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($blogQuery) > 2) {
                $width = '100%';
            } else if (mysqli_num_rows($blogQuery) > 1) {
                $width = '100%';
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i <= mysqli_num_rows($blogQuery); $i++) {
                $row[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($blogQuery);
                $blog_id[$i] = $row[$i]['blog_id'];
                $blogDetails[$i] = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from blog where id = $blog_id[$i]");
                if (mysqli_num_rows($blogDetails[$i]) > 0) {
                    $rowblog[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($blogDetails[$i]);
                    $blogName[$i] = $rowblog[$i]['title'];
                    $blogImg[$i] = $website . $rowblog[$i]['img'];
                    $blogDesp[$i] = htmlspecialchars_decode($rowblog[$i]['desp']);
                    $blogData .= "<div style='width:100%;float:left;padding:7px;text-align:justify'><span style='width:100%;padding-bottom:5px;float:left'><img src='" . $blogImg[$i] . "' width='30%' height='30%' style='max-width:100px;max-height:100px'></span><b style='vertical-align:bottom'>" . $blogName[$i] . "</b><span style='font-size:12px;'>" . $blogDesp[$i] . "</span></div>";
                }
                $validate++;
            }
        }
        $message = $templateMsg . $blogData;
    } else {
        $message = $templateMsg;
    }
    $messageFinal = '<div style="width:100%">' . $message . '</div>';
    echo $validate;
} else {
    echo "Fail";
    exit();
}
$subscribers = explode(',', $_POST['subscribers']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($subscribers); $i++) {
    $to = $subscribers[$i];
    $subject = $template;
    $from = 'demo@demo.com';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Create email headers
    $headers .= 'From: Demo' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: Your Email Id' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // Compose a simple HTML email message
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>';
    $message .= $messageFinal . $footer;
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    // Sending email
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        $validate++;
    } else {
        $validate = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: i m using this code in my module to send user saved templates or HTML  to the people who have subscribed to its newsletter

Comment: it allow users to include the products or blogs saved on its website in the template he/she wants to send to their subscribers

Comment: is not a good idea to paste large amounts of code without explain what it does. Try to edit your answers, to leave only the essential parts and also explain in your own words what is the intended behavior of the code.